# realloc a struct, c

Tags: c, realloc

I have the next struct

```
struct Board
{
    int width;
    int height;
    char **board;
}
```

And I would like to expand the **board, meaning I need more memory and thus the call to
realloc(). So my question is how do I do that - should I call realloc() on every line in the array separatly and the call it on the entire struct?
Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to call `malloc` not `realloc` on `board`. When you instantiate an object of `Board`, no memory is allocated to the member `board` ; so it's not a question of reallocating memory, but **allocating** memory to `board` in the usual way for [multidimensional arrays](http://c-faq.com/~scs/cclass/int/sx9b.html).

```
#include <stdlib.h>

int **array;
array = malloc(nrows * sizeof(int *));
if(array == NULL)
    {
    fprintf(stderr, "out of memory\n");
    exit or return
    }
for(i = 0; i < nrows; i++)
    {
    array[i] = malloc(ncolumns * sizeof(int));
    if(array[i] == NULL)
        {
        fprintf(stderr, "out of memory\n");
        exit or return
        }
    }
```

Once, you've allocated memory, and then if you need to expand `board` (e.g. `board` was initially 2x2 and now you want it to be 6x6), call `realloc` in the same order you called `malloc` to initialize `board`.

Answer (score 1):

Call `realloc` for `board` to increase the number of elements by 1, and then call `malloc` on `board[height]` (assuming height is the first dimension) to add a new row

Answer (score 0):

If you want more lines, you should call `realloc` on `board`, if you want to expand lines, you need to call `realloc` on each line you previously allocated (e.g. `board[0]`, `board[1]` etc)

Answer (score 0):

If you can predict how much memory you need, it would be the best to only call it once. Doing otherwise might slow down the whole suff massively.